# Why is the thermoelectric figure of merit denoted by $ZT$?

Tags: physics, terminology, notation, thermodynamics, solid-state-physics

Why is the thermoelectric figure of merit denoted by $Z T$? Does $Z T$ come from the abbreviation of words in some language?

Update: So far, $T$ has been figured out — it is the temperature, to make the whole quantity dimensionless. So, the question is left only for $Z$.

Comment: Possibly German?

Comment: @Farcher I do not think so. According to Google translation, _thermoelektrischen_  _Gütefaktor_ is corresponding to _thermoelectric_ _figure_ _of_ _merit_ --- the letter "Z" does not even appear in the German word.

Comment: I guess because German Physicists were very much involved in the foundations of Thermodynamics..

Answer (score 2):

The concept of the thermoelectric figure of merit and the abbreviation ZT were introduced by the Russian physicist Abram Fedorovich Ioffe in 1949, so I assume the acronym originates from Russian. However all the references I can find are behind paywalls so frustratingly I cannot tell you how ZT is derived.

If your university has access to it, Ioffe's book where all this is described is Ioffe AF (1957) Semiconductor thermoelements, and Thermoelectric cooling.

Comment: In that book, it is just denoted as a lowercase "z", rather than the uppercase "ZT".

Comment: While according to Goldsmid, H. J. _Introduction to Thermoelectricity_, Springer-Verlag Berlin Heidelberg, 2016, "ZT" is dimensionless, and "T" there means temperature.

Comment: @AlexanderZeng: I've seen it as both *zT* and *ZT*. I don't know how Ioffe used it because I don't have access to his papers.

Comment: So the point is, you take the original figure of merit $Z$ and multiply by tempurature $T$ to make it dimensionless.  The result is $ZT$.  So half the answer is "$T$ stands for tempurature".  Now we just need to know where $Z$ comes from.

Comment: It cannot be a Russian acronym. In Russian a "thermoelectric figure of merit" is "термоэлектрическая добротность". Nothing resembles Z or З, neither graphically nor phonetically.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar Yes, that is true.

Comment: @user58697 Thanks for providing the information about Russian!

Answer (score 2):

My guess for the **Z**

From [THIS](http://tureng.com/en/german-english/figure%20of%20merit) Germain-English dictionary, we see that "Figure of merit" in German could be

**Gütezahl**  $\qquad$  or  $\qquad$  **Leistungskennzahl**

in electrical engineering.  So probably the letter **Z** is for **Zahl**, the German word for "number".

[moral: use Google translate with a grain of salt]

Comment: This seems plausible. Just wanted to add that the Z might also come from the word _Ziffer_ (as in _thermoelektrische Kennziffer_ which translates to _thermoelectric indicator_). _Ziffer_ is a synonym for _Zahl_ that is perhaps more frequently used in the sciences and engineering. (Disclaimer: I'm German.)